# HTML Encode & URLs

Tags: .net, regex, escaping, html-encode, linkify

I have an input string that must be stripped from html codes, so I use the default .Net function .HtmlEncode() to escape all dangerous characters.

Now I'm trying to replace URL's in the input string, to HREF anchors through a regular expression.

The problem is that when I 'linkify' the URL's before calling .HtmlEncode() the anchor tags get lost, which is logical. But when I do the linkify AFTER calling .HtmlEncode(), some url's get malformed because they contained dangerous characters?

It seems like a chicken-egg problem, how should one solve this?

Example:

Input string:

> `See http://example.com/q=1&x=2`

Expected outcome:

> `See <a
>   href="http://example.com/q=1&x=2">http://example.com/q=1&amp;x=2</a>`

Doing HtmlEncode first, calling Linkify after:

> `See <a
>   href="http://example.com/q=1&amp;x=2">http://example.com/q=1&amp;x=2</a>`

Doing Linkify first, calling HtmlEncode after:

> `See &lt;a
>   href=&quot;http://example.com/q=1&amp;x=2&quot;&gt;http://example.com/q=1&amp;x=2&lt;/a&gt;`

The solution I currently use is to call .HtmlDecode() on all matches found by the regular expression (linkify), but it's not 100% foolproof, since a valid URL could theoreticly contain a pattern like `&amp;` which will be decoded, but shouldn't.

Comment: Perhaps include a simple example?  It is not clear what exactly the linkification process entails.

Comment: What is this "linkify" regex utility?

Comment: @JeremyStein Just a regular expression like this one: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html

Comment: @Joshua the example doesn't have a replace portion.  That's a fine way to match, but is insufficient for replacing.  I'll post an answer...

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a cross-site scripting attack waiting to happen.

[Test link to google.](http://www.google.com)

Most approaches I've seen which convert user-input into HTML markup use some sort of "reserved" custom non-HTML sequence to accomplish this, for example, the link above actually looks like this in the Stack Overflow editor:

```
[Test link to google.][1]    

  [1]: http://www.google.com
```

Other rich UI interfaces do something similar.  It is not HTML but gets parsed and later output as HTML.
I'm not sure if this approach will work in your case, but it may be worthwhile.  You generally want to avoid giving someone the ability to input raw HTML into your application unless you trust them (and since your HtmlEncoding some of it, it looks like you don't really trust them).

Comment: I already allow fontstyles and line-breaks via ubb-codes like [b] for bold, and [br] for breaks, so I could just add [url] as a requirement for URL's, but it would only help in finding the URL's in the plain text, not in preventing HtmlEncode() from screwing things up ;) I could temporarily encode them with something like Base64, do the HtmlEncode, and then de-code them back, but it doesn't seem like a proper solution.

Comment: I was reading a Drupal book and found that there is a pseudo-standard of what I called the "reserved custom non-HTML sequence" -- BBCode.  I did a quick search for .NET BBCode and came up with the following:  http://eksith.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/aspnet-bbcode-c/  There is also a link on that page titled "better alternative" that looks on track with the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to treat normal text and links differently. So, first split the input into parts:

```
If you don't believe me that 1 < 2, see http://example.com/q=1&x=2
```

becomes a collection with two members:

```
{ "If you don't believe me that 1 < 2, see ", "http://example.com/q=1&x=2" }
```

You encode the first one and make a link out of the second one, encoding only the text of the link:

```
{
    "If you don't believe me that 1 &lt; 2, see ",
    "<a href=\"http://example.com/q=1&x=2\">http://example.com/q=1&amp;x=2</a>"
}
```

You then join the results into the final result.

But maybe it would be better if you used library that is made for producing HTML. Either [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or ASP.NET, depending on your needs.

Comment: The Linkify function is a single RegEx expression, if I want to use your work-around, I must write a very complicated function for link-detection myself. And I don't produce the HTML, it's user input from a form, so I cannot use any libraries for producing HTML.

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you use a library?

Comment: The libary is for parsing html input, so I cannot use it because my input is plain text, it shouldn't contain any HTML. The only thing I need to do is converting (plain text) links to html anchors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a regex replacement.  You need to run the href attribute through a urlencode and the link text through an htmlencode.

Comment: My current solution is to run HtmlEncode() on the string, do the RegEx.Replace(), and run HtmlDecode on the HREF. This works for 99% of the cases, but theoreticly there is a possibility that a valid link contains HTML encoded parameters, which shouldn't be decoded. But I never saw such an URL before ;)

Comment: I don't understand how you're able to write code to identify the href attributes to call HtmlDecode, but you're not able to write code to identify links and handle them properly.

Comment: Perhaps I would understand if you showed us the code you're using.